# puppet: create symlink and keep files in original directory

Tags: postgresql, puppet

The software I am installing via puppet in Centos7 creates a default folder with some files inside that folder. However, I would like to move that directory to another directory via a symlink. 
I manage to get it working for one run with the following code:

```
  #create symlink for xlog partition
  file { '/pglogs/94/':
    ensure  => present,
    source  => "/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_xlog/",
    recurse => true,
  } ->
  file { '/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_xlog/':
    ensure => 'link',
    target => '/pglogs/94/',
    force  => true,
  }
```

But from the second run I get errors:

> Notice: /Stage[main]/Dap::Dwh/File[/pglogs/94/]: Not removing
>   directory; use 'force' to override Notice:
>   /Stage[main]/Dap::Dwh/File[/pglogs/94/]: Not removing directory; use
>   'force' to override Error: Could not remove existing file Error:
>   /Stage[main]/Dap::Dwh/File[/pglogs/94/]/ensure: change from directory
>   to link failed: Could not remove existing file Notice:
>   /Stage[main]/Dap::Dwh/File[/pglogs/94/archive_status]: Dependency
>   File[/pglogs/94/] has failures: true Warning:
>   /Stage[main]/Dap::Dwh/File[/pglogs/94/archive_status]: Skipping
>   because of failed dependencies Notice:
>   /Stage[main]/Dap::Dwh/File[/pglogs/94/000000010000000000000001]:
>   Dependency File[/pglogs/94/] has failures: true Warning:
>   /Stage[main]/Dap::Dwh/File[/pglogs/94/000000010000000000000001]:
>   Skipping because of failed dependencies Notice:
>   /Stage[main]/Dap::Dwh/File[/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_xlog/]:
>   Dependency File[/pglogs/94/] has failures: true Warning:
>   /Stage[main]/Dap::Dwh/File[/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_xlog/]: Skipping
>   because of failed dependencies

It should not try to copy the files again when the symlink is already created. But it seems it still tries..

Answer (score 2):

ok, I found the answer.

I forgot to add the 'links => follow' the the copy part. 
The code in the ends becomes something like this:

```
#create symlink for xlog partition
file { '/pglogs/94/':
  ensure  => present,
  source  => "/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_xlog/",
  recurse => true,
  links   => follow,
} ->
file { '/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_xlog/':
  ensure => 'link',
  target => '/pglogs/94/',
  force  => true,
}
```

The links => follow makes sure the copy statement knows that it are the files are already present.